# NSCoding issue with iOS 12

Tags: nsarray, nscoding

While using iOS 12, I encountered an issue:

I have a custom class named ClassA conforms NSCoding protocol, ClassA has a NSArray property, this array contains only one kind of custom ClassB's objcts, ClassB also conforms NSCoding protocol.

In my application, object of ClassA will be archived at one time and unarchived the next time. Everything works well under iOS 12.

Now with iOS 12, archive seems OK(archive will call ClassA and classB's encode function), while unarchive doesn't work properly: unarchive will call ClassA's encode function, but won't call ClassB's encode function(in iOS 11, it calls). The unarchived object of ClassB was totally wrong: it returns nil when called "isKindOfClass: [ClassB class]", typically it should return Yes or No.

I'm not sure if this issue was caused by iOS 12 system, anyone has an idea?